# add icon (font-awesome) to trackbacks & pingbacks

Tags: wordpress, icons, comments, trackback, pingback

Maybe is a simple question, but I'm trying to add an icon for tracbacks and pingbacks in my comment page of wordpress. If every comment have an user avatar I wanna each tracback and pingback have same font-awesome icon like avatar user.

Is this posible? Anybody know how to do it?

As always, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue.

I searched in my functions.php comment function and change

```
<?php get_avatar($comment, 96)?>
```

for this:

```
<?php $avatar=get_avatar($comment, 96);
            if (!$avatar) {
            echo '<i class="icon-XXX icon-2x pull-right" style="color:#d9534f</i>';//You can use a img too o whatever
            } else {
            echo $avatar;
            } ?>
```

This code works cause pingbacks and tracbacks return false to get_avatar ;)

I hope this will be helpful for somebody